# Qt and Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ld-preload

Here is my code:

tools.h

```
#include <QtCore/QObject>    
namespace Tinject
{
    class ProbeCreator : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

        public:
            explicit ProbeCreator();
            Q_INVOKABLE void createProbe();
            //void update();
    };
}
```

tools.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include "tools.h"    
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QMetaObject>

using namespace std;
using namespace Tinject;

ProbeCreator::ProbeCreator() {
    moveToThread(QCoreApplication::instance()->thread());

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "createProbe", Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void ProbeCreator::createProbe()
{
    printf("CREATE PROBE");
}

#include "tools.moc"
```

Before every

```
g++ (g++ -fPIC -o hook.so -shared -I/path/Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/include -L/path/Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core main.cpp)
```

i running

```
moc tools.h -o tools.cpp
```

then I try to inject this library hook. So I'm using `LD_PRELOAD` and I got the following error:

> hook.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12ProbeCreatorC1Ev

My main.cpp is:

```
#include "tools.cpp" 
using namespace Tinject; 
extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT 
void qt_startup_hook() 
{ 
  new ProbeCreator(); 
}
```

What is wrong in this?

Too many code, extra test :)

Comment: Its a linker error. Looks like missing library or wrong library version.

Comment: I know but how i can check what is wrong? :)

Comment: I would start by chechking where ProbeCreator is defined, if the library containting its definition is linked and if so - try recompile those library with the same compiler settings.

Comment: I transferred main.cpp from the comment section to the main question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your tools.cpp is not included in the sources or not compiled.

Answer (score 1):

> `#include "tools.cpp"`

This is wrong; you need to include the header:

```
#include "tools.h"
```

Additionally, as @StPiere points out, you need to include the source file `tools.cpp` *and* the generated `moc_*.cpp` file into linkage. How you do this with your custom call to `g++` you'll have try yourself; however I would suggest to use [`qmake`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) and set up a project file, which would also take care of `moc`ing and many other Qt specific details.